# im getting {{}} instead of getting value of the textbox in the C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs

unable to get the value of angular js value in Code behind. while showing its showing displaying correct but back end values not coming.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
       app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
           $scope.myCalc1 = qty * unitprice;
       });
</script>




  <div align="center" style="height:800px" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">



                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtQty" runat="server" ng-model="qty" />                          
                  <asp:Label ID="Label10" Text="Unit Price" runat="server" />

                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUnitPrice" runat="server" ng-model="unitprice" />

      <input type="text" ng-model="myCalc1" runat="server" id="txtTotalPriceExcludingtax" >
```

Comment: what is wrong with this question? This is perfectly valid question

Comment: may be you got some error in angularjs code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular is a *client side* framework not a *server side* Framework that is why you can't mixed ASP.NET with Angular and expect things to behave naturally. `Text` in an ASP.NET Textbox is server side property that will render differently in the HTML and not necessarily angular will understand what you are trying to do.

My recommendation to keep things more transparent and easy to read to get an angular value in an input text and transfer this value to the server side with a later ASP.NET POST

Try this:

**html**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myCalc1" runat="server" id="txtTotalPriceExcludingtax" >
```

In order to respect the MVVM model, I prefer this calculation either in a function or in variable:

**controller**

```
$scope.myCalc1 = qty*unitprice
```

Finally your **server side**

```
var totalprice = Convert.ToInt32(txtTotalPriceExcludingtax.Value);
```

Comment: maybe remove the ASP property *runat="server"* from the input html tag as this is not an ASP Textbox anymore ?

Comment: Yes it is correct but the attribute is useless right ?

Comment: Oh yes you were right I was not familiar with it, mb

Comment: i have edited question . can u tell where im wrong? im not getting output.error - Error: qty is not defined

Comment: where are you not getting it?

Comment: im getting error in browser console

Comment: if you use ngModel those variables only can be accessed through `$scope.qty` in your controller so `$scope.myCalc1 = $scope.qty * $scope.unitprice;`